# Convert YUV frames into RGBA frames with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, codec, yuv

I would like to develop an application which would be able to convert YUV frames into RGBA frames using the ffmpeg library. 
I have begun writing this code:

```
void Decode::video_encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

    printf("Encode video file %s\n", filename);

    /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder((enum AVCodecID)codec_id);

    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352; // Avant c'était du 352x288
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base = (AVRational){1,25};
    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    c->gop_size = 10;
    c->max_b_frames = 1;
    printf("Avant\n");
    c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_RGBA;// Avant c'était AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
    printf("Après\n");
    if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(4);
    }

    frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();// Dans une version plus récente c'est av_frame_alloc
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(5);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;
```

However, each time I run this application, the following error appears in my Linux terminal:

**[mpeg2video @ 0x10c7040] Specified pix_fmt is not supported**

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you believe your code is relevant to your question; your question suggests you'd like to do a pixel format conversion from YUV to RGB, for which you could e.g. use ffmpeg's [libswscale](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/swscale_8h.html). However, your code is creating a MPEG-1/2 encoder object and tries to encode RGB input data into MPEG-1/2. This is not possible, ffmpeg's MPEG-1/2 encoders only support YUV420P. I'm not quite sure what to recommend other than to figure out whether you want to encode MPEG-1/2 video, in which case your input should be YUV420P, not RGBA, or whether you want to do pixel format conversion, in which case you should use libswscale...